# Sampling from a distribution which results in heteroskedasticity

Tags: time-series, monte-carlo, heteroscedasticity

I have a pretty basic model whereby using a monte carlo approach I am seeking to recreate the monthly stock market returns over the last 30 years. Using the actual monthly returns of an index, I have created an empirical distribution from which I plan to draw random returns for the monte carlo simulation.

After examining the actual monthly returns of the index, I noticed that the data is stationary and does not have autocorrelation (as per an ADF test and autocorrelation plot), however it appears to display conditional heteroskedasticity.

Is there any way to randomly draw from the distribution such that the resulting time series will display conditional heteroskedasticity?

Here's a plot of the returns
[image]

Here's a plot of the squared residuals
[image]

Comment: Can you show us a plot of the data, and a plot which shows the conditional heteroskedasticity? I would start trying a gamma distribution, maybe ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I've updated the questions to include plots as requested. I'm using matlab and using the archtest function confirms the heteroskedasticity. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you willing to assume that a GARCH model is appropriate (in which case you can fit it, resample the standardized residuals and pass them through your fitted GARCH model), or are you looking for a completely non-parametric way of doing this?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have been thinking that GARCH is the easiest way to go. Out of curiosity, what non-parametric approach would you suggest?